# C# How to merge 3 documents, header, footer and body separated in each document with OpenXML and PowerTools?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, productivity-power-tools, power-tools-for-xml

I need help on how to merge 3 documents, one that only holds the footer and the other one hold the header.

It kind of works but it show some kind of message in the word that the section is ongoing or something. Which is only visible when editing the document. It seems like it a extra or duplicate copy of the section. Could anyone help me with this?

Orginal Question with source code:

http://ericwhite.com/blog/forums/topic/discard-footer-or-section-separatly/

```
public partial class Source
{
    public bool DiscardHeadersInKeptSections { get; set; }
    public bool DiscardFootersInKeptSections { get; set; }

    public bool IsDiscardingParts
    {
        get
        {
            return DiscardHeadersInKeptSections || DiscardFootersInKeptSections;
        }
    }
}

public static partial class DocumentBuilder
{
    private static void RemoveHeadersFromSections(WordprocessingDocument doc)
    {
        var mdXDoc = doc.MainDocumentPart.GetXDocument();
        var sections = mdXDoc.Descendants(W.sectPr).ToList();
        foreach (var sect in sections)
        {
            sect.Elements(W.headerReference).Remove();
        }

        doc.MainDocumentPart.PutXDocument();
    }

    private static void RemoveFootersFromSections(WordprocessingDocument doc)
    {
        var mdXDoc = doc.MainDocumentPart.GetXDocument();
        var sections = mdXDoc.Descendants(W.sectPr).ToList();
        foreach (var sect in sections)
        {
            sect.Elements(W.footerReference).Remove();
        }

        doc.MainDocumentPart.PutXDocument();
    }

    private static void ProcessSectionsForLinkToPreviousHeaders(WordprocessingDocument doc)
    {
        CachedHeaderFooter[] cachedHeaderFooter = new[]
        {
            new CachedHeaderFooter() { Ref = W.headerReference, Type = "first" },
            new CachedHeaderFooter() { Ref = W.headerReference, Type = "even" },
            new CachedHeaderFooter() { Ref = W.headerReference, Type = "default" },
        };

        var mdXDoc = doc.MainDocumentPart.GetXDocument();
        var sections = mdXDoc.Descendants(W.sectPr).ToList();
        var firstSection = true;
        foreach (var sect in sections)
        {
            if (firstSection)
            {
                var headerFirst = FindReference(sect, W.headerReference, "first");
                var headerDefault = FindReference(sect, W.headerReference, "default");
                var headerEven = FindReference(sect, W.headerReference, "even");

                if (headerEven == null)
                {
                    if (headerDefault != null)
                        AddReferenceToExistingHeaderOrFooter(doc.MainDocumentPart, sect, (string)headerDefault.Attribute(R.id), W.headerReference, "even");
                    else
                        InitEmptyHeaderOrFooter(doc.MainDocumentPart, sect, W.headerReference, "even");
                }

                if (headerFirst == null)
                {
                    if (headerDefault != null)
                        AddReferenceToExistingHeaderOrFooter(doc.MainDocumentPart, sect, (string)headerDefault.Attribute(R.id), W.headerReference, "first");
                    else
                        InitEmptyHeaderOrFooter(doc.MainDocumentPart, sect, W.headerReference, "first");
                }

                foreach (var hf in cachedHeaderFooter)
                {
                    if (sect.Elements(hf.Ref).FirstOrDefault(z => (string)z.Attribute(W.type) == hf.Type) == null)
                        InitEmptyHeaderOrFooter(doc.MainDocumentPart, sect, hf.Ref, hf.Type);
                    var reference = sect.Elements(hf.Ref).FirstOrDefault(z => (string)z.Attribute(W.type) == hf.Type);
                    if (reference == null)
                        throw new OpenXmlPowerToolsException("Internal error");
                    hf.CachedPartRid = (string)reference.Attribute(R.id);
                }

                firstSection = false;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                CopyOrCacheHeaderOrFooter(doc, cachedHeaderFooter, sect, W.headerReference, "first");
                CopyOrCacheHeaderOrFooter(doc, cachedHeaderFooter, sect, W.headerReference, "even");
                CopyOrCacheHeaderOrFooter(doc, cachedHeaderFooter, sect, W.headerReference, "default");
            }
        }

        doc.MainDocumentPart.PutXDocument();
    }

    private static void ProcessSectionsForLinkToPreviousFooters(WordprocessingDocument doc)
    {
        CachedHeaderFooter[] cachedHeaderFooter = new[]
        {
            new CachedHeaderFooter() { Ref = W.footerReference, Type = "first" },
            new CachedHeaderFooter() { Ref = W.footerReference, Type = "even" },
            new CachedHeaderFooter() { Ref = W.footerReference, Type = "default" },
        };

        var mdXDoc = doc.MainDocumentPart.GetXDocument();
        var sections = mdXDoc.Descendants(W.sectPr).ToList();
        var firstSection = true;
        foreach (var sect in sections)
        {
            if (firstSection)
            {
                var footerFirst = FindReference(sect, W.footerReference, "first");
                var footerDefault = FindReference(sect, W.footerReference, "default");
                var footerEven = FindReference(sect, W.footerReference, "even");

                if (footerEven == null)
                {
                    if (footerDefault != null)
                        AddReferenceToExistingHeaderOrFooter(doc.MainDocumentPart, sect, (string)footerDefault.Attribute(R.id), W.footerReference, "even");
                    else
                        InitEmptyHeaderOrFooter(doc.MainDocumentPart, sect, W.footerReference, "even");
                }

                if (footerFirst == null)
                {
                    if (footerDefault != null)
                        AddReferenceToExistingHeaderOrFooter(doc.MainDocumentPart, sect, (string)footerDefault.Attribute(R.id), W.footerReference, "first");
                    else
                        InitEmptyHeaderOrFooter(doc.MainDocumentPart, sect, W.footerReference, "first");
                }

                foreach (var hf in cachedHeaderFooter)
                {
                    if (sect.Elements(hf.Ref).FirstOrDefault(z => (string)z.Attribute(W.type) == hf.Type) == null)
                        InitEmptyHeaderOrFooter(doc.MainDocumentPart, sect, hf.Ref, hf.Type);
                    var reference = sect.Elements(hf.Ref).FirstOrDefault(z => (string)z.Attribute(W.type) == hf.Type);
                    if (reference == null)
                        throw new OpenXmlPowerToolsException("Internal error");
                    hf.CachedPartRid = (string)reference.Attribute(R.id);
                }

                firstSection = false;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                CopyOrCacheHeaderOrFooter(doc, cachedHeaderFooter, sect, W.footerReference, "first");
                CopyOrCacheHeaderOrFooter(doc, cachedHeaderFooter, sect, W.footerReference, "even");
                CopyOrCacheHeaderOrFooter(doc, cachedHeaderFooter, sect, W.footerReference, "default");
            }
        }

        doc.MainDocumentPart.PutXDocument();
    }
}
```

Line:393 in DocumentBuilder.cs

```
                                if (source.KeepSections && source.IsDiscardingParts)
                                {
                                    if(source.DiscardHeadersInKeptSections)
                                    {
                                        RemoveHeadersFromSections(doc);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        ProcessSectionsForLinkToPreviousHeaders(doc);
                                    }

                                    if(source.DiscardFootersInKeptSections)
                                    {
                                        RemoveFootersFromSections(doc);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        ProcessSectionsForLinkToPreviousFooters(doc);
                                    }
                                }
                                else if (source.KeepSections)
                                    ProcessSectionsForLinkToPreviousHeadersAndFooters(doc);

                                List<XElement> contents = doc.MainDocumentPart.GetXDocument()
                                    .Root
                                    .Element(W.body)
                                    .Elements()
                                    .Skip(source.Start)
                                    .Take(source.Count)
                                    .ToList();
                                try
                                {
                                    AppendDocument(doc, output, contents, source.KeepSections, source.InsertId, images);
                                }
                                catch (DocumentBuilderInternalException dbie)
                                {
                                    if (dbie.Message.Contains("{0}"))
                                        throw new DocumentBuilderException(string.Format(dbie.Message, sourceNum));
                                    else
                                        throw dbie;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        using (OpenXmlMemoryStreamDocument streamDoc = new OpenXmlMemoryStreamDocument(source.WmlDocument))
                        using (WordprocessingDocument doc = streamDoc.GetWordprocessingDocument())
                        {
#if TestForUnsupportedDocuments
                            // throws exceptions if a document contains unsupported content
                            TestForUnsupportedDocument(doc, sources.IndexOf(source));
#endif
                            if (source.KeepSections && source.IsDiscardingParts)
                            {
                                if(source.DiscardHeadersInKeptSections)
                                {
                                    RemoveHeadersFromSections(doc);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    ProcessSectionsForLinkToPreviousHeaders(doc);
                                }

                                if(source.DiscardFootersInKeptSections)
                                {
                                    RemoveFootersFromSections(doc);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    ProcessSectionsForLinkToPreviousFooters(doc);
                                }
                            }
                            else if (source.KeepSections)
                                ProcessSectionsForLinkToPreviousHeadersAndFooters(doc);
```

How I use it

```
sources.Add(new Source(settings.TemplateFilePath, false));
sources[0].DiscardFootersInKeptSections = true;
sources[0].DiscardHeadersInKeptSections = true;

sources.Add(new Source(tempHeaderPath, true) { DiscardFootersInKeptSections = true });
sources.Add(new Source(tempFooterPath, true) { DiscardHeadersInKeptSections = true });
```

Document.xml

```
        <w:p w:rsidR="005C6B96" w:rsidRPr="00B14B81" w:rsidRDefault="005C6B96" w:rsidP="004F23F1"/>
        <w:p w:rsidR="00077D08" w:rsidRDefault="00D14262">
            <w:pPr>
                <w:sectPr w:rsidR="00077D08" w:rsidSect="0018015B">
                    <w:footerReference w:type="even" r:id="rId7"/>
                    <w:footerReference w:type="default" r:id="rId8"/>
                    <w:headerReference w:type="first" r:id="rId9"/>
                    <w:footerReference w:type="first" r:id="rId10"/>
                    <w:type w:val="continuous"/>
                    <w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838" w:code="9"/>
                    <w:pgMar w:top="1418" w:right="1418" w:bottom="2552" w:left="1418" w:header="318" w:footer="851" w:gutter="0"/>
                    <w:cols w:space="708"/>
                    <w:titlePg/>
                    <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
                </w:sectPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Josh Gomez</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
            <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
        </w:p>
        <w:p w:rsidR="00D14262" w:rsidRDefault="00D14262"/>
        <w:sectPr w:rsidR="00D14262" w:rsidSect="0018015B">
            <w:footerReference w:type="even" r:id="rId11"/>
            <w:footerReference w:type="default" r:id="rId12"/>
            <w:footerReference w:type="first" r:id="rId13"/>
            <w:type w:val="continuous"/>
            <w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838" w:code="9"/>
            <w:pgMar w:top="1418" w:right="1418" w:bottom="2552" w:left="1418" w:header="318" w:footer="851" w:gutter="0"/>
            <w:cols w:space="708"/>
            <w:titlePg/>
            <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
        </w:sectPr>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

Comment: Please include the code *you're using* in your question; don't link to an outside site. Please also quote the *exact* message you're seeing.

Comment: @CindyMeister The thing is that the message is Swedish, but I will try a English Office version tomorrow and see what it says.

Comment: Actually, I think I see what that is, a Continuous Section Break. The document.xml you provide shows that the document contains two Sections (Abschnitt in German, in case that's anything close to the Swedish). The first is w:type "continuous" and must have been added by your code. The second is "native" to the document (always present in EVERY document). I don't see anything in the code you provide, however, that would be adding a section...

Comment: @CindyMeister Yes that what I think it is. So the first one that is inside <w:pPr> is the "error"? Can I remove it and all its parts by id and it should solve the problem? It must be the powertools code that add another section because it try to merge footer and header document into the section free body document. But looking in the powertool source it is hard for me to find where I can fix it.

Comment: These don't have ids. What you'd need to do is query for sectPr elements that are a child element of pPr (paragraph properties). The tool's code does this, which gets all sections: var sections = mdXDoc.Descendants(W.sectPr).ToList(); You need to change this to get the paragraph property decendents, then the section property elements. I can't tell you the exact syntax, though, since this tool appears to have "wrapped" the Open XML SDK objects. You'll need to do some research...

Comment: @CindyMeister I just want to say I solved the problem. First it was another “bug” which made the section references different.

It was actually a duplicated which contained same section reference actually 6 reference in both section which was identical so I just had to search for sections with duplicated id and remove the first one and it’s parent <w:pPr>.